# Do devas ever make mistakes?

Tags: gods, philosophy

Do devas ever make mistakes, or are they infallible in all their actions?

Are there any examples of devas committing mistakes? And if so, are these real mistakes or merely play?

If we have to obey the devas completely, doesn't that mean that they cannot make mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Word Mistake has various meanings. In this context we can take 2 meanings. Mistake is some action or decision that: 1) Do not produce positive or desired results 2) Is against the shastra (like Vedas, Smrutis).

Word Deva means "shiny", "exalted", "heavenly being", "divine being", "anything of excellence". Deva are not the most supreme beings. However, they are considered better than humans. But they can commit mistakes (of both the types). You will find many examples in our Puranas.

It is human psychology to deny (or overlook or justify) the mistakes of someone who we worship or admire. We also attribute all the possible qualities to the Devas. One of which can be – someone who never commit mistakes. Existence of a being that has all the qualities and unlimited power is not possible. You must read a philosophical problem called Problem of Evil. To understand that please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_evil.

Comment: Thx for posting this reply. “ Mistake is some action or decision that: 1) Do not produce positive or desired results” <——  As someone who has made many many mistakes, this made me laugh  What an accurate description 

Comment: Sometimes mistakes can also lead to something useful! See these: https://www.inc.com/tim-donnelly/brilliant-failures/9-inventions-made-by-mistake.html, https://www.indiatimes.com/trending/social-relevance/popular-products-invented-by-accident-537511.html?picid=2093673

Comment: Yep, def the case many times  Thx for the links @Kaushik And also Happy New Year ! :) 

Comment: @Kaushik This explanation doesn't work, because there's a difference between allowing evil to happen and actively doing evil.

Comment: Of course the devas allow evil to happen, but do they commit evil themselves?